# Display a custom field under WooCommerce single product title

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I have problem with a custom fields in WooCommerce.

I have tille of product (book) and i want add author with custom field. I done it with register in theme custom fields and i add new one with Wordpress custome field.

Custom fields call: **`product_author`** (that is my)  and **`mbt_publisher_name`** (from theme)

I have found the template file **`title.php`** in theme and in woocommerce directory.

I tried to add:

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($id, "product_author", true); ?>
```

and nothing change... 
orignal source from title.php

```
    <?php
/**
 * Single Product title
 *
 * @author  WooThemes
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 1.6.4
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

?>

<h2 itemprop="name" class="product_title entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
```

what should I do to display that custom field under title? 
Where I can find that hook?

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you look at the woocommerce template [**`content-single-product.php`**](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/3.0/templates/content-single-product.php) you will see this code *(starting on line 54):*

```
/**
 * woocommerce_single_product_summary hook.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_title - 5
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_rating - 10
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_price - 10
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_excerpt - 20
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart - 30
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_meta - 40
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_sharing - 50
 * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_product_data() - 60
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' );
```

So **`woocommerce_template_single_title`** is hooked in **`woocommerce_single_product_summary`** action hook with a priority of **`5`** *(so it comes first).*

**You can do it in 2 Ways:**

1) you can use a custom function hooked in **`woocommerce_single_product_summary`** hook with a priority between **6** to **9**, this way:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_action_after_single_product_title', 6 );
function custom_action_after_single_product_title() { 
    global $product; 

    $product_id = $product->get_id(); // The product ID

    // Your custom field "Book author"
    $book_author = get_post_meta($product_id, "product_author", true);

    // Displaying your custom field under the title
    echo '<p class="book-author">' . $book_author . '</p>';
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

This code is tested and works on WooCommerce 3.0+

---

Or

2) You can edit directly the template **[`single-product/title.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/3.0/templates/single-product/title.php)** located in the WooCommerce folder **of your active theme** *([see below the reference about overriding WooCommerce templates through theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/))*:

```
<?php
/**
 * Single Product title
 *
 * @author  WooThemes
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 1.6.4
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

// Calling global WC_Product object
global $product;

$product_id = $product->get_id(); // The product ID

// Your custom field "Book author"
$book_author = get_post_meta($product_id, "product_author", true);

?>

<h2 itemprop="name" class="product_title entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

<p class="book-author"><?php echo $book_author; ?></p>
```

Official reference: [Template Structure + Overriding WooCommerce Templates via a Theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)

> I recommend you the first method because it's cleaner as it uses a hook and you will not need to make any changes if templates are updated. You should also better use a child theme…

Comment: The second way is correct :) nice... Thank You so much... may I ask one more Question to you?? I Would like create link to all books of author... it is possible?? i have some function in theme with bottom (called "by...'author' added like user not an author of book)  but is is in wrong place (under price - I can't find where is it) and URL show 404 error page.

Comment: Thanks again @LoicTheAztec for helping us with the understanding of WooCommerce architecture.